# Get distinct/unique documents by term with Elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Some context: I'm trying to set up a rule for an Elastic alert. Alert should trigger when some task fails more than 9 times. Logs about task failures are in documents that contain a string "Message".

Logs look something like:

```
Action with ID 12345 failed. (ExecutionCount: 123) Reason: ...<snip>
```

I wrote an Elasticsearch query that will get all logs where some action failed more than 9 times like this:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "span_near" : {
        "clauses" : [
            { "span_multi" : { 
                "match": {
                    "regexp": {"Message": "failed"}
                }
            }},
            { "span_multi" : { 
                "match": {
                    "regexp": {"Message": "executioncount"}
                }
            }},
            { "span_multi" : { 
                "match": {
                    "regexp": {"Message": "~[0-9]"}
                }
            }}
        ],
        "slop" : 0,
        "in_order" : true
    }
  }
}
```

Which works for filtering the desired log messages, but as an action keeps failing, *ExecutionCount* will increment and I'll get logs for same action multiple times.

This results in alerts that send hundreds of messages for a same action.

So I get Documents with messages:

```
Action with ID 1 failed. (ExecutionCount: 111) Reason: ...
Action with ID 2 failed. (ExecutionCount: 222) Reason: ...
Action with ID 3 failed. (ExecutionCount: 333) Reason: ...
Action with ID 2 failed. (ExecutionCount: 223) Reason: ... [Redundant]
Action with ID 1 failed. (ExecutionCount: 112) Reason: ... [Redundant]
```

But would like (Execution count doesn't matter as long it is above 9):

```
Action with ID 1 failed. (ExecutionCount: 111) Reason: ...
Action with ID 2 failed. (ExecutionCount: 222) Reason: ...
Action with ID 3 failed. (ExecutionCount: 333) Reason: ...
```

Is it possible to get distinct documents by some term (Action ID in this case) with free text search?
Something like another query on results the previous query returned? The position of action IDs will always be the same.

Unfortunately it is not possible to index the data in another, more useful way..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the collapse parameter to collapse search results based on field values. The collapsing is done by selecting only the top sorted document per collapse key, for more information you can check Elasticsearch official documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/collapse-search-results.html).

So your query should look like this:

**Query:**

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "span_near" : {
        "clauses" : [
            { "span_multi" : { 
                "match": {
                    "regexp": {"Message": "failed"}
                }
            }},
            { "span_multi" : { 
                "match": {
                    "regexp": {"Message": "executioncount"}
                }
            }},
            { "span_multi" : { 
                "match": {
                    "regexp": {"Message": "~[0-9]"}
                }
            }}
        ],
        "slop" : 0,
        "in_order" : true
    }
  },
  "collapse": {
    "field": "Action ID" # Field you want               
  },
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but it only works for a single value field.  All information I have is in a single field - the message field, it is not split in multiple fields. Seing how silly this is, I'm looking into splitting that data in to fields with Logstash though

Comment: Maybe you can use runtime fields to do the split on runtime you can check runtime fields here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/runtime.html